# Rails 5: Add options for select if check_box equals true

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I am trying to display different options for users to select in the show.html.erb, when the provider chooses to offer sets.

The problem is that the provider has multiple options, 1 bottle, 3 bottles, 6 and 12 bottles.

My _form.html.erb abstract:

```
<% if @wine.is_1 == true %>
     <%= f.select :bottles, [["1 bottle", "1"]], id: "bottle", prompt: "Select...", class:"form-control" %>
    <% end %>

<% if @wine.is_3 == true %>
     <%= f.select :bottles, [["3 bottles", "3"]], id: "bottle", prompt: "Select...", class:"form-control" %>
    <% end %>

<% if @wine.is_6 == true %>
         <%= f.select :bottles, [["6 bottles", "6"]], id: "bottle", prompt: "Select...", class:"form-control" %>
        <% end %>
```

Is there any alternative using the Reservations Controller to make the code minimal ? And how would I get the total amount to pay ?

Reservations Controller

```
class ReservationsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!
def create
  wine = Wine.find(params[:wine_id])

  if current_user == wine.user
    flash[:alert] = "You cannot book your own wine!"
  else

  start_date = Date.parse(reservation_params[:start_date])

  @reservation = current_user.reservations.build(reservation_params)
  @reservation.wine = wine
  @reservation.price = wine.price
  @reservation.total = wine.price * #bottles
  @reservation.save

  flash[:notice] = "Booked Successfully!"
end
  redirect_to wine

end
```

Comment: If I'm understanding correctly, you want to minimise the code in ReservationsController?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could use some helpers to avoid all that logic in the view. An example:

```
module ApplicationHelper
  def wine_quantity(wine)
    case 
    when wine.is_1 then [["1 bottle", "1"]]
    when wine.is_3 then [["3 bottles", "3"]]
    when wine.is_6 then [["6 bottles", "6"]]
    when wine.is_12 then [["12 bottles", "12"]]
    else
    end
  end  
end
```

and in your `_form.html.erb` it could be reduced to this:

```
<%= f.select :bottles, wine_quantity(@wine), id: "bottle", prompt: "Select...", class:"form-control" %>
```